# Help with (what should be?) a simple exponential curve

Tags: curve-fitting

I'm admittedly not a math expert. I'm in the process of reverse engineering a piece of software and am stuck on finding a curve. The curve is used to convert a value (0-1) into a real world value. The docs label the curve as an exponential curve, but interestingly the steepness of the curve is dictated by specifying the output value midpoint. Maybe this is simple, and may strike some as a silly question, but I've been trying to figure this out for weeks.

These are the data points I'm provided with.

Input 0.0, 0.5, 1.0

Output 0.00002, 0.005, 0.5

I don't expect the work to be done for me, but if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi John Conrad, don't be embarrassed to ask "non expert questions" :-). I find it however very difficult to understand what you mean by "output value midpoint". I was also wondering why you post on this very forum, but it seems that you have some data in the form of (input,output) pairs, that you want to fit an exponentially increasing relation to, so something like $y = ax^b$, where $y$ is output and $x$ is input - is that correct? With only three data points, this is very shaky. But it would really help if you could write down the form of the equation that relates output to input.

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. By "output value midpoint", I mean the expected output if the input value is 0.5.

Comment: A little background (if it happens to be helpful) - I'm trying to better understand (through reverse engineering) a piece of software that controls an audio console. The application has a knob that controls a parameter in the hardware. When the knob is turned, a normalized value is sent to the hardware, and the value is mapped to a curve to provide a more meaningful value to the user. In this case, the parameter is the attack time of a noise gate.

Comment: When building the control in the UI, the original creator used an "exp" curve, which I assume is exponential, or at least pseudo-exponential, but rather than declaring an exponent, they declare a minimum, maximum, and midpoint (all output values).

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the *logarithm* of output against the input, you get three points that seem to be quite nicely aligned. We can fit a line by regression (although these are really few data points). We would then find the relation
$$
  \ln(\text{output})\approx -10.66 + 10.1266 \cdot\text{input}
$$
which translates to
$$
  \text{output} \approx 2.33 \cdot 10^{-5} \cdot \exp(10.13 \cdot\text{input})= 2.33\cdot 10^{-5} \cdot 25000^{\text{input}}. 
$$
The factor $10.1266$ is equivalent to the $b=\ln(25000)$ found by @leviva.

[image: log(output) against input]

The plot shows the three given points and the fitted line.

Here is the R-code to achieve that:

```
output <- c(.00002, .005, .5)
input <- c(0, .5, 1)

plot(input, log(output), pch = 16)

fitline <- lm(log(output) ~ input)
abline(coefficients(fitline))
```

And the values for the fit are obtained as

```
coefficients(fitline)
(Intercept)       input 
  -10.66706    10.12663
```

Edit: given the numbers are all rounded, you should be good to go with $$\text{output} = 0.00002 * 25000^\text{input}.$$

Comment: Huh! Points closer to the line than I expected. Good answer!

Comment: @leviva the log scale redefines the meaning of "close". I suspect that the "25000" and the other figures, too, come from some embellishment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a "simple exponential curve" is, and it would be great if you could specify the exact form of equation you want to fit.

Assuming that the curve is of the form $y=a*\exp(b*x+c)$

We can easily prove that the points you've specified do not sit on any single curve of this form.

We start by substituting the three points you've specified in the equation:

$0.00002=a*\exp(b*0+c)$
$0.005=a*\exp(b*0.5+c)$
$0.5=a*\exp(b*1+c)$

We then divide eq. 3 by eq. 2:
$100=\exp(b+c)/\exp(0.5b+c)$

Which becomes:
$100=\exp(0.5b)$

Leading to the solution for b:

$b=2\ln(100)$

All is fine until we do the same with eq. 3 and eq.1, leading to:

$25000=\exp(b)$

Or $b=\ln(25000)$

Since we have two contradicting values for b, these three points cannot be on any curve of the specified form. Leading us back to the question - what is a "simple exponential curve"?

Comment: Good explanation, and nice "manual solution" (+1)! You may perhaps want to either drop the factor $a$, or $c$, since $a*\exp(b*x+c)=\exp(b*x + \ln(a) + c)$.